# revit python shell issues running script / installing

Tags: shell, architecture, revit

I'm trying to get the 2016 revitpython shell installed on the comp and i'm having issues running the code.

I've installed the shell and set the path to ironpython 2.7.3 as instructed on this website

http://blog.productspec.net/2015/02/03/beginners-guide-to-python-in-autodesk-revit/

I've also followed multiple tutorials on trying to run scripts. This one seems to be the simplest for turning a sentence into all uppercase letters.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

app = __revit__.Application
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

t = Transaction(doc, 'convert text')
t.Start()
for el in uidoc.Selection.Elements:
    el.Text=el.Text.upper()
t.Commit()
```

i know a little bit of python and form what I can tell, this looks good but i get this error returned when trying to run.

[image]

Which is then has this under the dropdown for show details:

> Revit encountered a System.MissingMemberException: 'Selection' object
>   has no attribute 'Elements' at
>   IronPython.Runtime.Binding.PythonGetMemberBinder.FastErrorGet'1.GetError(CallSite
>   site, TSelfType target, CodeContext context) blah blah blah

[image]

all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the Revit 2016 SDK](http://images.autodesk.com/adsk/files/REVIT_2016_SDK.msi).  Selection.Elements was deprecated in 2015.  Try Selection.GetElementIds().  You will loop through a set of elementId's rather than an element and will need to use the Document.GetElement method to get the element object.

Comment: Thanks man, i did try those and I think it might have been the way it was writtin. I ended up finding this and it seemed to althought I havent tried the Selection.GetElementIds() yet or the Document.GetElement method.

is there a way to add a file? i'd try to upload the code but it says its soo many characters